# Sonar Scanner on windows keeps referring to UserAppdata/temp for jars

Tags: windows, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

My Sonar scanner bat keeps failing with

`Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\2\sonar-scanner-api-batch12899016477207279785.jar`

I cannot stop it from referring to **AppData** and nothing is in there.
I deleted *.sonar* folder on users home,
I set *sonar working directory* , *sonar user home*, *sonar project home* as args. But scanner keeps trying to find jars in this   **C:\Users***\AppData\Local\Temp\2** location.

Is there anyway to completely clear restart the sonar-scanner ?

Thanks in advance!!